# Matlab takes only 4 values of a digit for calculation

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code to combine zeros in a matrix.For example,if there are 3 zeros,then l will be equal to 0.3 and 0.3 will be put into the matrix B.If any other numbers are there, then they are put into matrix B without any change.

```
k=1;l=0;i=1;
A=J;
xx=size(A,2);
while(i<=xx)
    if(A(i)~=0)
        if(i==1 || A(i-1)~=0)
            B(k)=A(i);
            k=k+1;
            i=i+1;
        else
            if(A(i-1)==0)
               str=num2str(l);
               if(mod(l,10)==0)
                  str=fliplr(str);
                  str2=strcat('0.',str);
               else
                  str2=strcat('0.',str);
               end;
               num=str2num(str2);
               B(k)=num;
               k=k+1;
               B(k)=A(i);
               k=k+1;
               i=i+1;  
               l=0;
            end;
         end;
    else
        l=l+1;
        i=i+1;
    end;
end;
if(l~=0)
    str=num2str(l);
    str2=strcat('0.',str);
    num=str2num(str2); 
    B(k)=num;`
end;
```

Here,the value of 'l' became equal to 23440 and only the value 2344 was taken.So instead of 0.04432, matlab is storing this as 0.2344.How do I make 'l' take the value 23440?

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if it were indented.  MATLAB does this automatically in its editor if you let it.

Comment: What is `J` and where does it come from?

Comment: I indented it now.Is this okay?

Comment: This is just part of my code.J is a 240 x 320 array.

Comment: Can you provide a sample J matrix that we might be able to use for troubleshooting? Maybe a smaller matrix which produces a similar error.

Comment: That _is_ rather curious. Indeed `mod(23440,10)` is `0`, so you would expect the `if` branch with `str=fliplr(str)` to be executed. And flipping the string `23440` in my copy of MATLAB produces `04432`. So it's as if the `else` branch were being executed instead.

Comment: I am sorry,there is an error in my code but I don't know in which part it is.Take J=zeros(1,5000).The value of str2 should be 0.0005 but it is 0.5000.

Answer (score 1):

If the array ends in zeros (or contains *only* zeros), the statement `if(mod(l,10)==0) ...` is not executed. Instead the branch under `if(l~=0)` at the end of the script is executed, and the function `fliplr` is not used there.

You should probably write a function to take `l` as an input and return the number that should be appended to `B`. Then you can call that function in both places where you needed to deal with zeros.  (Also I would rename `l` to something that looks less like `1`, but that's not why the script doesn't work.)

Comment: I have done a very silly mistake! In the if statement after the while loop, I forgot to write the case for `mod(l,10==0);` It worked for a few cases after this. Please tell me if you find any more errors.Thank you for trying to help me :)